# How do I make Jenkins do anything on git commit?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've set up Jenkins. Meaning, I have Web UI now. But the documentation is sparse, and the most unclear thing to me is what makes Jenkins do anything when I do a commit to GitHub.

I see some Git/GitHub plugins, but how do I make them work? Or how do I check if they are working? The simplest way will probably do, but mentioning alternatives will make for a better answer probably.

And let me add this, I don't want Jenkins to build every project in GitHub organization.

Comment: See if this article helps - https://learning-continuous-deployment.github.io/jenkins/github/2015/04/17/github-jenkins/

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-webhook-configuration

Comment: You can use Git webhooks, as documented on the [Git Plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git), or fall back to the "Poll SCM for changes" option in a job. The GitHub plugin also [documents](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github#GitHubPlugin-GitHubhooktriggerforGITScmpolling) how to set up hooks to trigger jobs in Jenkins.

Comment: @nisargshah95 DoNhuVy Thanks for the links. I'm still trying to make it work. I see notifications [coming](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/ff8a147e8631b8378bcee07e1b13b253) from GitHub in System Log. But nothing happens. I have pipeline job created. It has "GIthub project" checked, "Project url" specified, and "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" checked as well. Project url basically matches what's in the log, except for trailing slash. But when I try to remove it, it reappears again. Is there anything I can check?

Comment: @ChristopherOrr With Pipeline job, I [see](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/IDcmoONKY1s) notifications coming from GitHub in Jenkins' System Log. But build doesn't get triggered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on type of job chosen.

For **Multibranch pipeline**, you've got to add Branch source. There you specify owner (GitHub user, who owns the repo). Choose/add GitHub user's credentials (e.g., Username with password). Choose repository. And click Save.

You've also got to add `Jenkinsfile` to the root of your repo, e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do a push, and you'll see your build in Build History.

For **Pipeline** job, you supposedly need to check "GitHub project", fill in the "Project url" text field (e.g., https://github.com/rails/rails), and check "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling". But I didn't make it work.

For **Freestyle projects**, you have to check "GitHub project" checkbox, specify "Project url" (like, https://github.com/rails/rails), choose Git for Source Code Management thing, specify Repository URL (like, git@github.com:rails/rails.git), and add/choose credentials for Jenkins to be able to check out the repo.

For the last thing you need "SSH Username with private key" credentials. One way would be to generate ssh key pair (`ssh-keygen`) under jenkins user. Specify name of GitHub user account, that has access to the repo, for Username. And "From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh" for Private Key.

You then check "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" checkbox. Also, you can add a build step to make sure it works. Like, "Execute shell" with "echo test" command.